# Newton-Raphson code missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r

```
library (pracma)
newtonRaphson
#this is the code of Newton-Raphson algorithm
#fun is the first derivative of log likelihood function
#dfun is the second
function (fun,x0,dfun=NULL, ... , maxiter=100, tol= .Machine$double.eps^0.5){
if (is.null(dfun)){
dfun<-function(x,...){
  h <- tol^(2/3)
  (fun(x+h,...) - fun(x-h,...))/(2*h)
  }
}
#starting value
x<- x0
fx<- fun(x,...)
dfx<-dfun(x,...)
niter<-0
diff<-tol + 1
#iteration
while (diff >= tol && niter <= maxiter){
niter<-niter+1
if (dfx==0){
  warning ("Slope is zero: no further improvement possible")
  break
}
diff<- -fx/dfx
x<-x+diff
diff<-abs(diff)
fx<-fun(x,...)
dfx<- dfun(x,...)
}
if (niter> maxiter){
warning ("Maximum number of iterations 'maxiter' was reached")
}
return(list(root=x, f.root=fx, niter=niter, estim.prec=diff))
}

x<-c(3.91,4.85,2.28,4.06,3.70,4.04,5.46,3.53,2.28,1.96,2.53,2.28,1.96,2.53,3.88,2.22,3.47,4.82,2.46,2.99,2.54,0.52,2.50)  

df=function(theta2){s=sum(sin(x-theta2)/(1-cos(x-theta2)));s}
d2f=function(theta2){s=sum(((cos(x-theta2))*(1-cos(x-theta2))-(sin(x-theta2))^2)/(1-cos(x-theta2))^2);s}
newtonRaphson(df,-0.418,d2f)
```

This is my code but I got this error:

```
Error in while (diff >= tol && niter <= maxiter) { : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I know it may have NA in the condition but it should have a TRUE/FALSE value in the condition of while. I do not know why.

Could anybody help me?

thanks a lot!

Comment: at `niter=6`, `fx` is `Inf`, `dfx` is `-Inf` so, at `niter=7`, `diff = NaN` (and `fx` and `dfx` are also `NaN`), which results in condition = NA, hence the error.

Comment: @CathG Thank you so much!  Maybe I did the derivative wrong

Comment: you're welcome. When you've got an error like that in a function, `debug` can really help. (`debug(newtonRaphson)` and then `newtonRaphson(df,-0.418,d2f)`)